# EWS GetStreamingEvents. Response is received only by timeout

Tags: ios, xml, office365, exchangewebservices, rapidxml

In my iOS app I'm trying to get streaming events from `EWS` following [this manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458792(v=exchg.150).aspx). So first I subscribe for notifications, receive a subscription id and then perform `GetStreamingEvents` request. The subscription process is successful, however getting streaming events is not. I receive a response only by timeout. Yes, it does contain all the notifications, so no problems with that but I expect to receive a response once an event has occurred not when the request time is up.

So I launched [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com) and examined the traffic of Mac Mail app. I can see that it receives one response right after making `GetStreamingEvents` request and then it successfully receives responses every time an event has occurred as expected. So I made my XML look exactly like Mac Mail app's but still no luck.

This is my `Subscribe` xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
  <t:RequestedServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2" />
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
  <m:Subscribe xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
     <m:StreamingSubscriptionRequest SubscribeToAllFolders="true">
        <t:EventTypes>
           <t:EventType>CopiedEvent</t:EventType>
           <t:EventType>CreatedEvent</t:EventType>
           <t:EventType>DeletedEvent</t:EventType>
           <t:EventType>ModifiedEvent</t:EventType>
           <t:EventType>MovedEvent</t:EventType>
           <t:EventType>NewMailEvent</t:EventType>
           <t:EventType>FreeBusyChangedEvent</t:EventType>
        </t:EventTypes>
     </m:StreamingSubscriptionRequest>
  </m:Subscribe>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and this is my `GetStreamingEvents` xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
  <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2" />
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
  <m:GetStreamingEvents xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
     <m:SubscriptionIds>
        <t:SubscriptionId>JwBkYjVwcjA2bWIxNDY0LmV1cnByZDA2LnByb2Qub3V0bG9vay5jb20QAAAAF9r7tBXj+U+UapGUZ4XFytKbA+ad1dQIEAAAAMiCIP/mQqJOjzx9Aog45Fk=</t:SubscriptionId>
     </m:SubscriptionIds>
     <m:ConnectionTimeout>30</m:ConnectionTimeout>
  </m:GetStreamingEvents>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Any ideas, guys?

UPDATE:

This is how I build my subscription:

```
bcstring SubscribeRequestMessage::buildSoapRequest() const
{
xml_document<> doc;
xml_node<>* decl = doc.allocate_node(node_declaration);
decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("version", "1.0"));
decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("encoding", "utf-8"));
doc.append_node(decl);

// Envelope
xml_node<>* envelope = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "soap:Envelope");
envelope->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("xmlns:soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"));
envelope->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("xmlns:t", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"));

doc.append_node(envelope);
{
    // Header
    xml_node<>* header = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "soap:Header");
    {
        xml_node<>* reqServerVersion = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "t:RequestedServerVersion");
        xml_attribute<>* serverVersionAttribute = doc.allocate_attribute("Version", m_requestedServerVersion.c_str());
        reqServerVersion->append_attribute(serverVersionAttribute);
        header->append_node(reqServerVersion);
    }
    envelope->append_node(header);

    // Body
    xml_node<>* body = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "soap:Body");
    {
        xml_node<>* subscribe = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "m:Subscribe");
        {
            subscribe->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("xmlns:m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"));

            xml_node<>* streamingSubscriptionRequest = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "m:StreamingSubscriptionRequest");
            {

                if (m_folderIds.size() > 0)
                {
                    xml_node<>* folderIds = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "t:FolderIds");
                    {
                        for (const bcstring& folderId : m_folderIds)
                        {
                            xml_node<>* folderIdNode = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "t:FolderId");
                            folderIdNode->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("Id", folderId.c_str()));
                            folderIds->append_node(folderIdNode);
                        }
                    }
                    streamingSubscriptionRequest->append_node(folderIds);
                }
                else
                {
                    xml_attribute<>* subscribeToAll = doc.allocate_attribute("SubscribeToAllFolders", "true");
                    streamingSubscriptionRequest->append_attribute(subscribeToAll);
                }
                xml_node<>* eventTypes = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "t:EventTypes");
                {
                    for (const bcstring& eventType : m_eventTypes)
                    {
                        xml_node<>* eventTypeNode      = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "t:EventType");
                        xml_node<>* eventTypeValueNode = doc.allocate_node(node_data, "", eventType.c_str());
                        eventTypeNode->append_node(eventTypeValueNode);
                        eventTypes->append_node(eventTypeNode);
                    }
                }
                streamingSubscriptionRequest->append_node(eventTypes);
            }
            subscribe->append_node(streamingSubscriptionRequest);
        }

        body->append_node(subscribe);
    }
    envelope->append_node(body);
}

bcstring retVal;
print(std::back_inserter(retVal), doc, print_no_indenting);

return retVal;
}
```

and this is how I build get streaming xml:

```
bcstring GetStreamingEventsRequest::buildSoapRequest() const
{
xml_document<> doc;
xml_node<>* decl = doc.allocate_node(node_declaration);
decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("version", "1.0"));
decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("encoding", "utf-8"));
doc.append_node(decl);

// Envelope
xml_node<>* envelope = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "soap:Envelope");
envelope->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("xmlns:soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"));
envelope->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("xmlns:t", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"));

doc.append_node(envelope);
{
    // Header
    xml_node<>* header = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "soap:Header");
    {
        xml_node<>* reqServerVersion = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "t:RequestServerVersion");
        xml_attribute<>* serverVersionAttribute = doc.allocate_attribute("Version", m_requestedServerVersion.c_str());
        reqServerVersion->append_attribute(serverVersionAttribute);
        header->append_node(reqServerVersion);
    }
    envelope->append_node(header);

    // Body
    xml_node<>* body = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "soap:Body");
    {
        xml_node<>* getStreamingEvents = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "m:GetStreamingEvents");
        {
            getStreamingEvents->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("xmlns:m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"));

            xml_node<>* subscriptionIds = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "m:SubscriptionIds");
            {
                for (const bcstring& subscriptionId : m_subscriptionIds)
                {
                    xml_node<>* subscriptionIdNode  = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "t:SubscriptionId");
                    xml_node<>* subscriptionIdValue = doc.allocate_node(node_data, "", subscriptionId.c_str());
                    subscriptionIdNode->append_node(subscriptionIdValue);
                    subscriptionIds->append_node(subscriptionIdNode);
                }
            }

            getStreamingEvents->append_node(subscriptionIds);

            xml_node<>* connectionTimeout      = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "m:ConnectionTimeout");
            bcstring connectionTimeoutString   = std::to_string(m_connectionTimeout);
            xml_node<>* connectionTimeoutValue = doc.allocate_node(node_data, "", connectionTimeoutString.c_str());
            connectionTimeout->append_node(connectionTimeoutValue);
            getStreamingEvents->append_node(connectionTimeout);
        }

        body->append_node(getStreamingEvents);
    }
    envelope->append_node(body);
}

bcstring retVal;
print(std::back_inserter(retVal), doc, print_no_indenting);

return retVal;
}
```

UPDATE:

This is the XML of Mac Mail app that I see via Charles:
Subscription:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
  <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2" />
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
  <m:Subscribe xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
     <m:StreamingSubscriptionRequest SubscribeToAllFolders="true">
        <t:EventTypes>
           <t:EventType>CopiedEvent</t:EventType>
           <t:EventType>CreatedEvent</t:EventType>
           <t:EventType>DeletedEvent</t:EventType>
           <t:EventType>ModifiedEvent</t:EventType>
           <t:EventType>MovedEvent</t:EventType>
           <t:EventType>NewMailEvent</t:EventType>
           <t:EventType>FreeBusyChangedEvent</t:EventType>
        </t:EventTypes>
     </m:StreamingSubscriptionRequest>
  </m:Subscribe>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

and streaming:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
  <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2" />
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
  <m:GetStreamingEvents xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
     <m:SubscriptionIds>
        <t:SubscriptionId>JwBkYjVwcjA2bWIxNDY0LmV1cnByZDA2LnByb2Qub3V0bG9vay5jb20QAAAADv7qpS0xbU6V0mCxt2SvFHYOYoCq1dQIEAAAAMiCIP/mQqJOjzx9Aog45Fk=</t:SubscriptionId>
     </m:SubscriptionIds>
     <m:ConnectionTimeout>30</m:ConnectionTimeout>
  </m:GetStreamingEvents>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

and this is the response from EWS arriving upon timeout and containing a notification about a new mail:

```
<Envelope
xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap11:Header
    xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ServerVersionInfo
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="1282" MinorBuildNumber="22" Version="V2017_04_14"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" />
    </soap11:Header>
    <soap11:Body
        xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <m:GetStreamingEventsResponse
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
            xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
            <m:ResponseMessages>
                <m:GetStreamingEventsResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
                    <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
                    <m:ConnectionStatus>OK</m:ConnectionStatus>
                </m:GetStreamingEventsResponseMessage>
            </m:ResponseMessages>
        </m:GetStreamingEventsResponse>
    </soap11:Body>
</Envelope>
<Envelope
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap11:Header
        xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <ServerVersionInfo
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="1282" MinorBuildNumber="22" Version="V2017_04_14"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" />
        </soap11:Header>
        <soap11:Body
            xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <m:GetStreamingEventsResponse
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
                xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
                <m:ResponseMessages>
                    <m:GetStreamingEventsResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
                        <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
                        <m:Notifications>
                            <m:Notification>
                                <t:SubscriptionId>JwBkYjVwcjA2bWIxNDY0LmV1cnByZDA2LnByb2Qub3V0bG9vay5jb20QAAAA4mbQZqHZf0aA35Z5r1UEvPZtJfmw1dQIEAAAAMiCIP/mQqJOjzx9Aog45Fk=</t:SubscriptionId>
                                <t:CreatedEvent>
                                    <t:TimeStamp>2017-07-28T12:06:04Z</t:TimeStamp>
                                    <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGZmMjA4MmM4LTQyZTYtNGVhMi04ZjNjLTdkMDI4ODM4ZTQ1OQBGAAAAAADKa2Su6/EXRrsmOefDSCL3BwBEITO0krAyRbRmLsC3JNeGAAAAAAEMAABEITO0krAyRbRmLsC3JNeGAAAdPAOsAAA=" ChangeKey="CQAAAA==" />
                                    <t:ParentFolderId Id="AAMkAGZmMjA4MmM4LTQyZTYtNGVhMi04ZjNjLTdkMDI4ODM4ZTQ1OQAuAAAAAADKa2Su6/EXRrsmOefDSCL3AQBEITO0krAyRbRmLsC3JNeGAAAAAAEMAAA=" ChangeKey="AQAAAA==" />
                                </t:CreatedEvent>
                                <t:NewMailEvent>
                                    <t:TimeStamp>2017-07-28T12:06:04Z</t:TimeStamp>
                                    <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGZmMjA4MmM4LTQyZTYtNGVhMi04ZjNjLTdkMDI4ODM4ZTQ1OQBGAAAAAADKa2Su6/EXRrsmOefDSCL3BwBEITO0krAyRbRmLsC3JNeGAAAAAAEMAABEITO0krAyRbRmLsC3JNeGAAAdPAOsAAA=" ChangeKey="CQAAAA==" />
                                    <t:ParentFolderId Id="AAMkAGZmMjA4MmM4LTQyZTYtNGVhMi04ZjNjLTdkMDI4ODM4ZTQ1OQAuAAAAAADKa2Su6/EXRrsmOefDSCL3AQBEITO0krAyRbRmLsC3JNeGAAAAAAEMAAA=" ChangeKey="AQAAAA==" />
                                </t:NewMailEvent>
                                <t:ModifiedEvent>
                                    <t:TimeStamp>2017-07-28T12:06:04Z</t:TimeStamp>
                                    <t:FolderId Id="AAMkAGZmMjA4MmM4LTQyZTYtNGVhMi04ZjNjLTdkMDI4ODM4ZTQ1OQAuAAAAAADKa2Su6/EXRrsmOefDSCL3AQBEITO0krAyRbRmLsC3JNeGAAAAAAEMAAA=" ChangeKey="AQAAAA==" />
                                    <t:ParentFolderId Id="AAMkAGZmMjA4MmM4LTQyZTYtNGVhMi04ZjNjLTdkMDI4ODM4ZTQ1OQAuAAAAAADKa2Su6/EXRrsmOefDSCL3AQBEITO0krAyRbRmLsC3JNeGAAAAAAEIAAA=" ChangeKey="AQAAAA==" />
                                    <t:UnreadCount>1</t:UnreadCount>
                                </t:ModifiedEvent>
                            </m:Notification>
                        </m:Notifications>
                    </m:GetStreamingEventsResponseMessage>
                </m:ResponseMessages>
            </m:GetStreamingEventsResponse>
        </soap11:Body>
    </Envelope>
    <Envelope
        xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap11:Header
            xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <ServerVersionInfo
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="1282" MinorBuildNumber="22" Version="V2017_04_14"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" />
            </soap11:Header>
            <soap11:Body
                xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <m:GetStreamingEventsResponse
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
                    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
                    <m:ResponseMessages>
                        <m:GetStreamingEventsResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
                            <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
                            <m:ConnectionStatus>OK</m:ConnectionStatus>
                        </m:GetStreamingEventsResponseMessage>
                    </m:ResponseMessages>
                </m:GetStreamingEventsResponse>
            </soap11:Body>
        </Envelope>
        <Envelope
            xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soap11:Header
                xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <ServerVersionInfo
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="1282" MinorBuildNumber="22" Version="V2017_04_14"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" />
                </soap11:Header>
                <soap11:Body
                    xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <m:GetStreamingEventsResponse
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
                        xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
                        <m:ResponseMessages>
                            <m:GetStreamingEventsResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
                                <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
                                <m:ConnectionStatus>OK</m:ConnectionStatus>
                            </m:GetStreamingEventsResponseMessage>
                        </m:ResponseMessages>
                    </m:GetStreamingEventsResponse>
                </soap11:Body>
            </Envelope>
            <Envelope
                xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <soap11:Header
                    xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <ServerVersionInfo
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="1282" MinorBuildNumber="22" Version="V2017_04_14"
                        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" />
                    </soap11:Header>
                    <soap11:Body
                        xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                        <m:GetStreamingEventsResponse
                            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                            xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
                            xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
                            <m:ResponseMessages>
                                <m:GetStreamingEventsResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
                                    <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
                                    <m:Notifications>
                                        <m:Notification>
                                            <t:SubscriptionId>JwBkYjVwcjA2bWIxNDY0LmV1cnByZDA2LnByb2Qub3V0bG9vay5jb20QAAAA4mbQZqHZf0aA35Z5r1UEvPZtJfmw1dQIEAAAAMiCIP/mQqJOjzx9Aog45Fk=</t:SubscriptionId>
                                            <t:ModifiedEvent>
                                                <t:TimeStamp>2017-07-28T12:07:39Z</t:TimeStamp>
                                                <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGZmMjA4MmM4LTQyZTYtNGVhMi04ZjNjLTdkMDI4ODM4ZTQ1OQBGAAAAAADKa2Su6/EXRrsmOefDSCL3BwBEITO0krAyRbRmLsC3JNeGAAAAAAEMAABEITO0krAyRbRmLsC3JNeGAAAdPAOsAAA=" ChangeKey="CQAAAA==" />
                                                <t:ParentFolderId Id="AAMkAGZmMjA4MmM4LTQyZTYtNGVhMi04ZjNjLTdkMDI4ODM4ZTQ1OQAuAAAAAADKa2Su6/EXRrsmOefDSCL3AQBEITO0krAyRbRmLsC3JNeGAAAAAAEMAAA=" ChangeKey="AQAAAA==" />
                                            </t:ModifiedEvent>
                                            <t:ModifiedEvent>
                                                <t:TimeStamp>2017-07-28T12:07:39Z</t:TimeStamp>
                                                <t:FolderId Id="AAMkAGZmMjA4MmM4LTQyZTYtNGVhMi04ZjNjLTdkMDI4ODM4ZTQ1OQAuAAAAAADKa2Su6/EXRrsmOefDSCL3AQBEITO0krAyRbRmLsC3JNeGAAAAAAEMAAA=" ChangeKey="AQAAAA==" />
                                                <t:ParentFolderId Id="AAMkAGZmMjA4MmM4LTQyZTYtNGVhMi04ZjNjLTdkMDI4ODM4ZTQ1OQAuAAAAAADKa2Su6/EXRrsmOefDSCL3AQBEITO0krAyRbRmLsC3JNeGAAAAAAEIAAA=" ChangeKey="AQAAAA==" />
                                                <t:UnreadCount>0</t:UnreadCount>
                                            </t:ModifiedEvent>
                                        </m:Notification>
                                    </m:Notifications>
                                </m:GetStreamingEventsResponseMessage>
                            </m:ResponseMessages>
                        </m:GetStreamingEventsResponse>
                    </soap11:Body>
                </Envelope>
                <Envelope
                    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <soap11:Header
                        xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                        <ServerVersionInfo
                            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="1282" MinorBuildNumber="22" Version="V2017_04_14"
                            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" />
                        </soap11:Header>
                        <soap11:Body
                            xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                            <m:GetStreamingEventsResponse
                                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
                                xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
                                <m:ResponseMessages>
                                    <m:GetStreamingEventsResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
                                        <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
                                        <m:ConnectionStatus>Closed</m:ConnectionStatus>
                                    </m:GetStreamingEventsResponseMessage>
                                </m:ResponseMessages>
                            </m:GetStreamingEventsResponse>
                        </soap11:Body>
                    </Envelope>
```

Comment: So the traffic is there, but it's not giving a response within the code?

Comment: the response is given only upon connection timeout specified here <m:ConnectionTimeout>30</m:ConnectionTimeout>. while I need a response every time an event is happening. This is the problem

Comment: ok, weird. Can you paste your other code?

Comment: sure. anything. what exactly would you like to see?

Comment: sorry should have been clear, the subscription and streaming initialisation.

Comment: updated my question with the code which builds subscription and streaming. please take a look

Comment: in the for loop in the subscription code 'doc.allocate_node(node_element, "t:EventType")' are all the types getting allocated?

Comment: yes, CopiedEvent, CreatedEvent, DeletedEvent,ModifiedEvent, MovedEvent, NewMailEvent, FreeBusyChangedEvent. All seven. Just like needed. You can see them in the final XML. They are there

Comment: I think I misunderstood you before, Charles is saying the only response is timeout right, there's nothing else going back and forth? So it could be an issue at their end as well?

Comment: no, no, no. Charles reads the traffic of the Mac Mail app. And it shows that the response for the Mac Mail app is received 1) Right after making request 2) Every time an event occurs. 3)When time is up.  And this is what I'm trying to achieve. But in my case I receive response only for the 3rd case - when the time is up. I don't think the problem is at their end because Mac Mail app works ok. So something must be wrong at my side. But my XML for both subscription and streaming is precisely like I see in Charles. So I have no idea what am I doing wrong

Comment: Is my question unclear somehow? Maybe my English is too Ukrainian and western people don't quite get it? Should I edit it?

Comment: haha no, your English is fine. You are subscribing to all folders: '<m:StreamingSubscriptionRequest SubscribeToAllFolders="true">' - it is *exactly* the same code as the mail.app?

Comment: I will post Mac Mail app subscription and streaming XMLs in a minute

Comment: updated my question

Comment: What code do you get for the timeout?

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: Am I reading this wrong, it looks like 6 envelopes: 'OK' + 'Create/New/Mod' + 'No Error' + 'No Error' + 'Mod/Mod' + 'Closed' ? So we can see the mods and such?

Comment: yeah, 6 envelops. instead of each one arriving when needed they all arrive together when the time is up

Comment: Crappy workaround: have a lower timeout and recall.

Comment: this is what I'm doing. Temporary solution, 1 min timeout and recall, but that is awful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"GetStreamingEvents" responses really *are* streamed.

This means that the http connection stays open, and the notifications are sent through it in more of a continuous flow than a standard request/response mechanism. This is similar to the way streaming a video works. You don't do a single request for the entire video. Instead, you would read the streamed data from the video as it is being sent, and process it accordingly.

You need to handle responses to "GetStreamingEvents" in a similar fashion.

The details provided in the question don't show how you are handling the responses, but  I'm guessing that you are using an API that simply fetches a URL and returns a response. That works great for standard requests like the "StreamingSubscriptionRequest", but it won't work for streamed responses.

APIs that simply fetch a url won't return until a complete response is received and/or the connection is closed. That's why it seems like you're not receiving the streamed events until the timeout expires.

In fact, you *are* receiving those events, you're just not reading them and processing them as they come in.

To do that, you'll need to use an API that allows to you connect to an http server and read from that connection as the data arrives. For iOS, this is as simple as implementing the [connection didReceiveData:] delegate method on NSURLConnection. Presumably, there is some similar higher-level mechanism that can be used in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem once, but I don't know if it is the same for you. I was using EWS over HTTP with chunked transfer encoding and also received responses only at timeout. It turned out that a terminating 0 chunk was only sent at timeout, not after each response, therefore I was always waiting for more data until the timeout.

Note that it is not too bad to have a low timeout since you might want to use multiple subscriptions in a single GetEvents request and you can't add or remove subscriptions from a running GetEvents request.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer but it's not entirely clear for me. A chunked transfer encoding? Can you elaborate what is that please? I'm following this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458792(v=exchg.150).aspx. Is that what you were doing? Sorry for dumb questions